# Turning Textbox Red with a timer when serial port stops outputting data

Tags: c#, textbox, serial-port

I am building a GUI that reads in serial data into a textbox.  If there is a problem and the instrument stops working, I want the textbox to turn red.  I am trying to do this with a timer, so the timer will read data every 30 seconds, then if there is no data, the timer will then turn the textbox red.  However, nothing happens when I unplug the instrument.  How can I turn the textbox red when the instrument stops working?

Here is the relevant code:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan span = GPSlastdatatime - timenow;
        timespan = Convert.ToDouble(span.TotalSeconds);

        if (timespan > 30)
        {
            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume "GPSlastdatatime" is set whenever data comes in?

As is, your "timespan" value is going to be **negative**.

Switch the order of your subtraction line:

```
TimeSpan span = timenow - GPSlastdatatime;
```

By the way, you could do it all in one line like this:

```
timespan = (DateTime.Now - GPSlastdatatime).TotalSeconds;
```